# Python 3.1 and MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I've been trying to get MySQL working with Python, but I haven't been able to find any scripts that work with it :(

I can't find a 3.1 compatible setuptools, easy_install or MySQLdb package. What should I be using?

Comment: You should also be using Python 3.2.x. Python 3.1 is obsolete and no longer maintained; plus, Python 3.2 contains many, many fixes and performance improvements over 3.1.  Also, `setuptools` has been superseded by the `Distribute` package, which also provides `easy_install`.

Comment: SQLAlchemy, what about trying to use ORM? Isn't sqlalchemy released for python 3+ yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like PyMySQL is working with 3.1 with the right build options, but I haven't tried it myself yet:
https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/#python-3-0-support

Answer (score 0):

In case you aren't using windows, you can use mypysql 
http://mypysql.sourceforge.net/